# Cygwin shell doesn't execute .bashrc

Tags: shell, cygwin

After start the cygwin shell, it just locate in a wrong home dir:

```
xfire@codingme.com ~
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Users/xfire
```

But it used to be /home/xfire

```
xfire@codingme.com /etc
$ cat passwd | grep xfire
xfire:unused:22773:10513:U-CORP\xfire,S-1-5-21-527237240-725345543-682003330-12773:/home/xfire:/bin/bash
```

And the .bashrc in the /home/xfire was not executed, even I copy it to the /cygdrive/c/Users/xfire, it also doesn't work!

Comment: Check this out: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2002-01/msg00826.html

Comment: Some program add an "HOME" environment in windows registry and set the value to "C:\Users\xfire", that's why cygwin take that directory as the home. http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html

Comment: Useless use of cat: `grep xfire passwd`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some program add an "HOME" environment in windows registry and set the value to "C:\Users\xfire", that's why cygwin take that directory as the home. cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html

Comment: Too bad this was your own answer and therefore wasn't bumped to the top when you selected it as the correct answer, because the two top-voted answers are essentially useless if the HOME variable isn't set how you expect.

Comment: I mean, I know it works if I delete it, but what if I still HOME in windows?

Comment: Thanks, this is it. In my case, this "HOME" environment variable is set to "%USERPROFILE%". In cmd, "echo %USERPROFILE%" : C:\Users\myuser.  So .bashrc and bash_profile files must be there. But like me, you might not need them, and simply edit the cygwin system file "C:\cygwin64\etc\bash.bashrc"

Comment: If you use your Cygwin home folder, then instead set the "HOME" to "C:\cygwin\home\xfire". It will automatically source the `.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really confusing because even when I echoed $HOME, `/cygdrive/c/users/myname` looks a lot like `/home/myname`. I would have noticed right away if it said `C:\Users\myname`.

Answer (score 43):

On cygwin, I add this to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This solved it for me. Maybe you could clarify what's going on, and why Evans Y. wants to accept his answer?

Comment: For others that may be curious why.  The cygwin default terminal program is mintty.  If you check the properties for the icon you use to launch the terminal, you will find that it ends with a lone "-".  This tells mintty to run the shell as a login shell.  Bash in turn only executes .bashrc if the shell is **not** a login shell.  For login shells it only executes .bash_profile (or .profile).  In many other unixes, the terminal programs start the shell as a non-login shell so they execute the .bashrc by default instead of .bash_profile.

Answer (score 5):

On my version of cygwin I found that only `~/.profile` was being execueted so added

```
if [ -e "${HOME}/.bash_profile" ]; then
    source "${HOME}/.bash_profile"
fi
```

to the `.profile` file. My `.bash_profile` file contains another test for `.bashrc` and executes that from inside there. I also added the following two lines to my `.bashrc` file.

```
export BASH_ENV="${HOME}/.profile"
export ENV="${HOME}/.profile"
```

The first of these ensures that `.profile` gets executed in non-interactive terminals and the second ensures it gets executed in POSIX terminals. I found a very useful explanation of what get run and when in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

In your case it wouldn't help as you have an issue with the value of your `HOME` environment variable but this page comes up quite high on the list when searching for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can also also set BASH_ENV variable, e.g., BASH_ENV='C:\DOCUME~1\dwyttenb\.bashrc'

Comment: This can be quite dangerous. `BASH_ENV` is for non-interactive, non-login shells only (`bash` started without `-i` or `--login`).  For example, if you invoke a shell command from your editor, like a `make` or a `Build` script. It should be set to something like `BASH_ENV=~/.bash_env`.

Comment: I know what the documentation says but I don't understand the risk.

Comment: The rules behind `BASH_ENV`, .`bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are very well thought out.  If you want `.bashrc` executed why not simply running `bash -i`? `BASH_ENV` is useful when an editor or IDE runs `bash -c CMD`, or when running a remote command `ssh root@host bash -c CMD`. In these cases the shell is not interactive. With `BASH_ENV=~/.bash_env` it must only set PATH etc. in `~/.bash_env` but not define functions, aliases or PS1. Less risk.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bash_profile` is executed before the initial command prompt is returned to the user. After that, every time a new shell is opened, `~/.bashrc` is executed.

Adding `. ~/.bashrc`  at end of  `~/.bash_profile` has resolved the problem.

Now you can check existing aliases using `alias`  command.

Find more details on [github](https://github.com/saiprateek/bashrc).