# Cygwin doesn't find /.bashrc

Tags: windows, cygwin, bash

I install Cygwin on Windows 7 64bit, and my location on `/.bashrc` location is `C:/cygwin64/home/admin/bashrc`, but I can't see it from Cygwin, it's says:

> bash: /.bashrc: No such file or directory

What I try is to navigate to that folder with the command:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/admin/
```

and then use:

```
/.bashrc
```

but it says:

> No such file or directory

What to do to see that file?

Comment: Perhaps, it's because your $HOME is not set properly, or your `passwd` file is not populated during installation. Try running `mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd`. Run `mkpasswd --help` for other options `mkpasswd` takes.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on my Cygwin installation.

> CYGWIN_NT-6.1 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) x86_64 Cygwin

I created a ~/.bashrc file in my (cygwin) home directory, but the aliases I set up did not work.

The problem was that I did not have a ~/.bash_profile file in my home directory. It must contain the following line to recognize the desired .bashrc

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

I created it by appending the needed line

```
echo ". ~/.bashrc" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

See [StackOverflow > Cygwin shell doesn't execute .bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815927/cygwin-shell-doesnt-execute-bashrc)

Comment: Note: if your .bash_profile ends in a comment line instead of a newline, the appended line may end up as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify: this is has nothing to do with Cygwin. It is normal Bash behavior.

*~/.profile*: The login script filename originally used by */bin/sh*.

*~/.bash_profile*: The personal initialization file, executed for login shells

*~/.bashrc*: The individual per-interactive-shell startup file.

Each new Cygwin window (each invocation of *Cygwin.bat*) opens a login shell, because there is no *init* process and you are already logged in as Windows user. In *Cygwin.bat* Bash is invoked so: `bash --login -i`.

Because of `--login` the *~/.bash_profile* is executed. More specifically, Bash reads */etc/profile* and then *~/.bash_profile*, *~/.bash_login*, and *~/.profile*, in that order, and executes the first one that is readable.

Because of `-i` the *~/.bashrc* should be executed too. But it isn't because Bash only executes *.bashrc* for a shell that's both interactive and non-login.

Note that `bash --login -i --rcfile=C:/Cygin/home/%USERNAME%/.bashrc` won't work either, because `--rcfile` is silently ignored in case of login shells.

Therefore it is good practice to hook *$HOME/.bashrc* in case of a true login shell (textual login shell).  This is the reason why many *.bash_profile* files contain the following lines:

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ]; then
    source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

Textual login shells appear when you ssh/telnet to a host, boot Linux into text mode or... run *Cygwin.bat*.

Having come this far I'd like to add a subtle point. Many Linux desktops read *~/.profile* (not *~/.bash_profile* or *~/.bash_login*) automatically by the Display-Manager during the start-up process desktop session. Therefore hook *~/.bashrc* in *~/.profile* too:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Because Bash executes *~/.profile* in absence of *~/.bash_profile* you may get away with only *~/.profile*.

Now you can do all customization in *~/.bashrc*.

Answer (score 0):

find your `$HOME` and can you try this command :

```
cd ~/

ls -la
```

if he doesn't exists create it.
or check this post : [Cygwin shell doesn't execute .bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815927/cygwin-shell-doesnt-execute-bashrc)

or tries

```
cat ~/.bashrc
```