# Can I Force XTerm.exe's Default BASH Shell and Other Non-Login Shells in Cygwin to Load ~/.bashrc?

Tags: shell, cygwin, bash, xterm

I'm having a problem with `Cygwin`, specific to `XTerm.exe` sessions not loading `BASH` configuration file(s) properly.

For starters, my `.startxwinrc` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
xterm -geometry +0+60 -ls &
xterm -geometry +0-100 &
exec  xclock
```

...and my .Xresources is:

```
Xft*antialias:          true
Xft*autohint:           true
XTerm*background:   white
XTerm*foreground:   black
XTerm*cursorColor:  orchid
XTerm*fullCursor: true
XTerm*reverseVideo: false
XTerm*geometry:   80x40
XTerm*scrollBar:    true
XTerm*rightScrollBar:   true
XTerm*scrollTtyOutput: off
XTerm*scrollKey: on
XTerm*reverseWrap: true
XTerm*saveLines:    10000
XTerm*faceName:     BitStream Vera Sans Mono
XTerm*faceSize:     12
XTerm*toolBar:      off
XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override\n\
        <Key>BackSpace: string(0x7F)\n\
        <Key>Delete: string("\033[3~")\n\
        <Key>Home: string("\033[1~")\n\
        <Key>End: string("\033[4~")\n\
        <KeyPress>Prior : scroll-back(1,page)\n\
        <KeyPress>Next : scroll-forw(1,page)
```

I start my X server as:

```
startxwin &
```

And I see the above configurations worked... I get two `XTerm` windows and a `xclock` (and the color and scroll, etc. are per my specifications).

But curiously the terminal prompt is not what I set it to in my `~/.bashrc` configuration file.

At first I thought my issue was related to these questions:
[Why is my .bashrc not read under cygwin?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19495/why-is-my-bashrc-not-read-under-cygwin)
[Cygwin shell doesn't execute .bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815927/cygwin-shell-doesnt-execute-bashrc)

...which suggest the issue is that the actual configuration settings are loaded from `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, perhaps.  But adding these did nothing.

To verify they weren't running I added a line like this to each of the three bash configuration files (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and `.profile`) in my home directory:

```
echo "**** EXECUTING /home/JasonMick/.bash_profile *****" | \
    tee -a /tmp/shell.log
```

The file is never written... so clearly these files are never touched.

Next I verified that there is no "HOME" variable in my Windows Environment Variables (which some suggested could be the source of such problems).  There was no such variable, so I was okay in that regard.

Next I verified some basic things about the shell state using...

```
printf '%s\n' $SHELL $HOME $USER
```

The results for the XTerm are:

> /bin/bash
>   /home/JasonMick
>   JasonMick

These results match identically to those of the same command executed in the non-`X11` terminal `mintty` (which I typically use to launch `startxwin`).  However when I open the new `mintty` the prompt is correct, per the settings in my home directory `.bashrc` file.

To be on the safe side, I searched for `.profile`, `.bashrc`, and `.bash_profile` files in `/etc/`.  I found the following files:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bash_profile
/etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bash_profile
/etc/defaults/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/defaults/etc/profile
```

I added prints to all of them.

In mintty I the /etc/shell.log file gets the following commands:

> **** EXECUTING /etc/profile ****
>   **** EXECUTING /etc/bash.bashrc *****
>   **** EXECUTING /home/JasonMick/.bash_profile *****

...so it appears to be calling the `/etc/` files, then  finally calling the `.bash_profile` in my home directory, automatically, without any source calls from the `/etc/` located configuration files.

Removing the log, I launch startxwin.  Xterm opens, but the log file isn't there!

This implies that XTerm isn't touching ANY configuration file.. not in `/etc/` not in `${HOME}`!

The only difference I've found is that when calling `echo $0 $-` in `mintty` I get:

> -bash himBH

...where as in XTerm I get:

> bash himBH

According to the info at:
[Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/37944)
[Why 'echo $0' gives different result for two different terminals?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114058/why-echo-0-gives-different-result-for-two-different-terminals)

My bash shell in the Xterm is an **interactive** (**i** flag in `$-`) non-login (no **-** at the front of `$0`) `BASH` shell, while my `mintty` is a **iteractive**, **login** `BASH` shell.

Okay.  Based on the second link above I still expect my **non-login** **interactive** shells to load my ~/.bashrc.  But again, as stated above it does not only not loading that file... they're not loading ANY bash configuration file as far as I can tell.  None in `${HOME}`... none in `/etc/`.

Any idea how to force the **non-login** shells in Cygwin (i.e. `XTerm` default shell session) to properly source `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that in `Cygwin` I can get the **non-login** shells to load their configuration settings by invoking `export ENV=~/.bashrc` in my `.startxwinrc` file.  The new `.startxwinrc` file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ENV=~/.bashrc
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
xterm -geometry +0+60 -ls &
xterm -geometry +0-100 &
exec  xclock
```

Bother `xterm` sessions and their children now correctly source my `~/.bashrc`.

@Gilles in the thread [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) states:
"When you start a shell in a terminal in an existing session (screen, X terminal, Emacs terminal buffer, a shell inside another, …), you get an **interactive, non-login** shell. That shell might read a shell configuration file (`~/.bashrc` for bash invoked as `bash`, `/etc/zshrc` and `~/.zshrc` for zsh, `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `~/.cshrc` for csh, the file indicated by the `ENV` variable for POSIX/XSI-compliant shells such as dash, ksh, and bash when invoked as `sh`, `$ENV` if set and `~/.mkshrc` for mksh, etc.)."

When I first read that, the first clause seemed to suggest that `~/.bashrc` is loaded automatically for **non-login** shells.  While the second clause does state that the variable `ENV` can be defined to set the configuration file location for `bash`, the language of the first clause makes it unclear whether this is necessary always or just sometimes?  Based on my findings, it's possible that "sometimes" is true for some platforms where the default GUI files include a call to export the `ENV` variable corresponding to the configuration file of the default shell.

@ThomasDickey's linked solution to a related question helped me to reevaluate @Gilles answer cited above.  However, his suggestion to change my `XTerm` calls to **login** shells is not something at this point I consider the best answer, as the only difference that was of concern to me was the inability to automatically load the shell configuration, which my fix remedies for **non-login** shells.

There are differences in calls to `uptime` and certain other reporting calls as [Difference between...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) states, but those aren't something I forsee being a concern for my use case.  My deployment is a single user local deployment using `Cygwin` with no intent to accept incoming `ssh` calls to my machine.  Hence there's not compelling reason I can find not to adopt the simpler one line fix which applies the proper configuration file via `${ENV}` to all `XTerm`s, rather than the somewhat more verbose fix of adding a flag to every `XTerm` call, telling it to launch its shell in **login** mode.

Answer (score 1):

You might have noticed this also: *[Run xterm with login shell or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35320/run-xterm-with-login-shell-or-not)*, which points out that xterm's `loginShell` resource can be used to tell it to act as a login shell.

Also, unset (or incorrectly set) `HOME` variable interferes with sourcing `.bashrc` on startup, according to the [Cygwin FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bashrc).  The FAQ mentions some [typical problems with `HOME`](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.home).

Comment: I appreciate your help, but want to give some constructive criticism on the edit to this answer.  I feel the text on `${HOME}` is somewhat extraneous, as I specifically show it IS set correctly in the **non-login** shell in question, and I further state that it is NOT set in my Windows environment variables. So the issues you bring up, while real, I'd already mentioned in the question text and clarified did not apply to my deployment.