# How to edit Pspad text files using cygwin

Tags: command-line, installation, cygwin, text-editor, pspad

how can I define ***Pspad*** to ***Cygwin*** ?

and

what are the commands required for text file editing ?

Comment: Try to use *vim*?

Comment: thank you for response martin, I'm interested  in Pspad .

Comment: Pspad is not installed to Cygwin by default. Please see this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/304541/how-to-install-new-packages-on-cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow easy launch of pspad from Cygwin command line, I have done the following steps :

- check where `$HOME` was set in Cygwin (by doing `echo $HOME` in bash)
- edit (with pspad) the file `$HOME/.bashrc`, writing in it :

  `export PATH=/cygdrive/c/my_path_to_pspad`
- I had to rename the  `.bashrc.txt` created by pspad into `.bashrc`
- add a file `$HOME/.bash_profile` and, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815927/cygwin-shell-doesnt-execute-bashrc), write in it

  `. ~/.bashrc`
- finally be able to launch pspad from the Cygwin command line.