# Running shell script on Windows via Cygwin mintty.exe doesn't execute runcoms

Tags: bash, cygwin

### Problem summary

I'm trying to launch a .sh script via Windows 10 Cygwin (i.e. mintty.exe > bash.exe) but neither .profile, .bash_profile, or .bashrc are loading, which I need to update PATH env variable with Cygwin's bin directory.

### Background

I'm trying to launch a script **finder.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
find .
read
```

from `C:\Users\Bo\Temp\`. It has unix line endings and executable bit set.

I have Cygwin installed at `C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\Programs\cygwin64\`. I do not have this path in either System or User Windows' **Environment Variables** (and I don't want to!). My runcoms all live in this directory under `/home/Bo`. My .bash_profile (and ATM .bashrc) have an `export PATH="/cygdrive/c/Users/Bo/AppData/Local/Programs/cygwin64/bin":${PATH}` in them.

I want to launch the script from **Windows Explorer**. I tried using the **bash.exe** and **mintty.exe** in the `cygwin64\bin\` folder via `Open > Choose another app > More apps > Look for another app on this PC`. In either case the mintty window displays:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

meaning the Windows' `find` command was used not Cygwin's. So I have my script echo **$PATH** and the `Cygwin/bin` directory is not in **PATH**. If I add the proper `export PATH` statement from above to my own script it works fine. So, now to debug the launcher and runcoms...

I've put `echo ${0}` statements in .profile, .bash_profile, and .bashrc, none of which trigger which I run the .sh script, they are never run. I've read SO and the mans. I've tried creating a Shortcut to both mintty.exe and bash.exe passing a variety of `-l -i -e -` commands to each using `Properties > Shortcut > Target` and they are never run. E.g. running simply `[..]\mintty.exe -h always` doesn't even leave the window open.

***How do I get my script to run in Windows Explorer via Cygwin's mintty.exe/bash.exe, and to read from a runcom to update PATH (to find Cygwin Linux commands, vs. updating Windows Environment Variable)?***

Comment: Can you create a shortcut, in which you will be able to specify `--rcfile ...` ?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I've removed the tag.

@Philippe, I just tried that, it doesn't seem like ANY arguments I pass to the Target field of a shortcut commend are being interpreted. I made a shortcut to `bash.exe` called `bash2.exe` and put `--rcfile [path].bash_profile` and is not called there either.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Just a heads-up that you can only tag one person per comment, so @Philippe didn't get the reply notification (until this comment/tag).

Comment: It's not in cygwin documentation. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoked-non_002dinteractively

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, I was expecting to find something there too alas the answer is in how bash.exe is invoked as being non interactive/login and looks for BASH_ENV. I set that to a custom runcom .bash_env where you export PATH to include Cygwin/bin. I wish this was made more clear anywhere. I can't be the first to scratch my head over it.

Comment: Please post the exact `mintty` command which you have defined in the Windows shortcut.

Comment: @user1934428 I didn't end up calling mintty.exe if you see my answer pt B. I realize it's in my Title but it was not needed to execute my intentions (run a .sh script). I thought I needed mintty.exe because that is the tty that Cygwin uses and I misunderstood (if you look at the Cygwin launcher > Properties > Shortcut > Target it uses "mintty.exe -i [icon] -"). However, I just need to run a script so don't need interactive/login and can just open/run the .sh using Open With... the bash.exe executable app (from Cygwin\bin) and leave mintty.exe out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two part fix:

A) set a Windows **Environment Variable** for `BASH_ENV` to a .bash_env under your Cygwin HOME, and export the PATH variable to include the Cygwin/bin directory from that file. I cannot find a decent reference for this in Cygwin documentation because it seems to be simply a **bash** thing, but this variable is what bash looks for when running non login/interactively. Best reference: [Cygwin shell doesn't execute .bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815927/cygwin-shell-doesnt-execute-bashrc#comment93018488_9907785).

And B) run the .sh with **bash.exe** from Cygwin/bin using **Open With...**.

ALSO, annoying Windows bug: when you select a program to **Open With...** your .sh script, it will *always* run 1x with a CWD from your C:\Windows\System32 directory(?!) and all other times will run fine with the CWD as the directory from your .sh script.